# Maui Map custom popup on click

Tags: maui

Is there a way to customise the popup displayed when clicking on a Pin in MAUI? I'm trying to drop a series of Pins and when the user interacts with them, I want a popup / overlay to be displayed near the pin. A bit like whats it doing now, but with far richer content

Model:

```
public partial class MapViewModel : ObservableObject
{
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(IsNotBusy))]
bool isBusy;

public bool IsNotBusy => !isBusy;

[ObservableProperty]
public List<Pin> pins;

public MapViewModel()
{
    pins = new List<Pin>()
    {
        new Pin{ Label="A", Address = "123 John Street", Location = new Location{ Latitude = 51, Longitude = 0.1}},
        new Pin{ Label="B", Address = "124 John Street", Location = new Location{ Latitude = 51.1, Longitude = 0.1}},
        new Pin{ Label="C", Address = "125 John Street", Location = new Location{ Latitude = 51.2, Longitude = 0.1}},
        new Pin{ Label="D", Address = "126 John Street", Location = new Location{ Latitude = 51.3, Longitude = 0.1}},
        new Pin{ Label="E", Address = "127 John Street", Location = new Location{ Latitude = 51.4, Longitude = 0.1}},
        new Pin{ Label="F", Address = "128 John Street", Location = new Location{ Latitude = 51.5, Longitude = 0.1}},
        new Pin{ Label="G", Address = "129 John Street", Location = new Location{ Latitude = 51.5, Longitude = 0.1}},
    };
}

[RelayCommand]
Task OnDoStuff()
{
    return Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//map");
}
```

Map.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/maps"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiNativeMap.ViewModels"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiNativeMap.Pages.Map"
             Title="Map">
    <maps:Map MapType="Street" x:Name="MyMap" ItemsSource="{ Binding pins}">
    
    </maps:Map>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Map : ContentPage
{
    MapViewModel vm => BindingContext as MapViewModel;


    public Map(MapViewModel vm)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm = new MapViewModel();
       
        vm.Pins.ForEach(p =>
        {
            MyMap.Pins.Add(p);
            p.MarkerClicked += async (s, args) =>
            {
                //I want to show custom content here?
                //await DisplayAlert("You clicked the pin", $"Pin was {p.Label}", "Cool");
            };
        });
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

        // Initialise the vm here - pull data from places etc
        MyMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Location { Latitude = 51, Longitude = 0.2 }, Distance.FromMiles(20)));
    }
```

I want to show custom content, maybe an image? When a user clicks on a pin on the map

Comment: May I ask what .NET version you are using? Which platform you are targeting on?

Comment: Latest version from .net8. Targeting both, android and iOS

Comment: When you click on the map, you could use a [Community Toolkit Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) instead of DisplayAlert. In Community Toolkit Popup, you could customize your own UI.

Answer (score 0):

[DisplayAlert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-8.0) is a simple pop up which is used to display a prompt. To show rich content, you could try using [CommunityToolkit Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) or designing your own custom control.

You may also want to use [Maui handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0) to customize your map pins for each platform. Also here is the article which you may refer to [Customize map pins in .NET MAUI](https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Customize-map-pins-in-.NET-MAUI/) and [its sample code](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main/MauiMaps) for Android or iOS. That may help you show an image when clicking on a map pin.

Hope it helps!